# Long press tap gesture recogniser for UICollectionView Objective-c

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I am using a UICollectionView in my ViewController for displaying images and i want that user should be able to delete photos on long press, but i am not able to detect long press gesture. I have read all the previous discussions and tried to implement them in my project also but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Have you enabled touch on imageview.?

Comment: @BhadreshMulsaniya no i have not enabled touch for imageview

Comment: After enabling working or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable user interaction for your imageview by below line

```
imgview.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
```

//Here is sample code

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[gestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(imgLongPressed:)];
gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
imgview.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
[imgview addGestureRecognizer: gestureRecognizer];

- (void) imgLongPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    UIImageView *view_ =(UIImageView*) sender.view;
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:view_.superview];

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {

    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {

    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: @CodeGuru Welcome :-)

Comment: Hey do you know how  allow user to re-arrange UICollectionVIew cells?

Comment: @CodeGuru Actually I have not tried but there is some demo available on github.